# gzip: FILE is a multi-part gzip file -- not supported

Tags: gzip

I am trying to restore some deleted files from one server.

Using several tools for raw disk scan, I found lots of files - gz, gif, jpg etc.
I also found some multi-part gzip files that I do not know how not handle.

This is what I get when I try to extract:

```
# gunzip myfile.gz 
gzip: myfile.gz is a multi-part gzip file -- not supported

# file myfile.gz 
myfile.gz: gzip compressed data, has CRC, has comment, last modified: Sun Dec 29 06:05:05 2019, max compression
```

Note that timestamp is wrong.

Is this corrupted file, incidental random "magic number" or there is a way to unzip it somehow.

Comment: Maybe you transferred it via FTP in ASCII mode? http://www.gzip.org/#faq2

Comment: no , it is something that come up from the disk using raw disk scan.